# HTML phrase markup with javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking the way to markup a phrase in an html with a javascript function. The thing is, I have a HTML page with a lot of words but I need to markup the phrase every time that appear. Does anyone has any idea how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "markup"? Is the phrase static or variable? Does the phrase contain any other html elements or can it? Is the phrase guaranteed to be wholly contained within an html element? You have not given us any examples of what you have tried to date or any information of how you want to mark up this phase. Please try to narrow the scope of your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can find with keyword like html replace or something which will be well suited to your situation.

By using gulp, there is gulp-html-replace module (https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-html-replace)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all your text is within p-tags, you can select all paragraphs by

```
var allP = document.getElementsByTagName("P")
```

Then loop over allP and get the html of the tag.

```
for (var i; i< allP.length; i++) {
    var thisP = allP[i];
    var htmlP = thisP.innerHTML;
}
```

Then you can split htmlP with your phrase (in the for loop), e.g.:

```
var partsP = htmlP.split("I want to be highlighted");
```

And den rebuilt your html:

```
var newHtmlP = "";
for (var j; j < partsP.length; j++) {
    newHtmlP = newHtmlP + partsP[j] + '<span style="color:red">I want to be highlithed</span>';
}
```

You have to make sure, that the phrase is not appended one time to much at the end (I did not implement this here).
Finally you set the inner html:

```
thisP.innerHTML = newHtmlP;
```